# Hudson/jenkins does not fail on errors

Tags: build, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

In my Hudson log I see error or fails, but hudson says ,that build is success.
Is it right?

This is what hudson does (run ant few times)

```
call f:\runGenericAntBuild.bat %WORKSPACE%  f:\general-build.properties %WORKSPACE%\build\buildProjects.xml deploy %BUILD_NUMBER%  %SVN_REVISION%

call f:\runGenericAntBuild.bat %WORKSPACE%  f:\general-build.properties %WORKSPACE%\build\buildProjects.xml MyJavaProject %BUILD_NUMBER%  %SVN_REVISION%

call f:\runGenericAntBuild.bat %WORKSPACE%  f:\general-build.properties %WORKSPACE%\build\buildProjects.xml buildGrails %BUILD_NUMBER%  %SVN_REVISION%

call f:\runGrailsClean.bat %WORKSPACE%\MyProject
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's common to write unit tests that pass when an exception is thrown--could this be what you're seeing in the logs?

Comment: No it is not 'normal' but you should provide more information (log content, job configuration, ...) otherwise it will be difficult to help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you got a single build step that is a batch step and it contains all four `call` commands?  If yes, thats your problem.

Your batch looks like its not doing anything with errors in any of the steps, so the status of the batch is the status of the last command (your clean step)

Either split it into four separate build steps within Hudson/Jenkins, or handle the errors in the batch script.

e.g.

```
 call f:\runGenericAntBuild.bat your params here || exit /b 1  
 call f:\runGenericAntBuild.bat next params here || exit /b 2
 call f:\runGenericAntBuild.bat third param here || exit /b 3
 call f:\runGrailsClean.bat more param as needed || exit /b 4
```

This way the batch will exit with an error of 1-4 depending on the step that failed.

Comment: Also in a similar vein I sometimes use this: `if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%`

Answer (score 2):

According to me Jenkins/Hudson is able to complete the Job successfully because it is able to complete the Job that is assigned to him. You might have not set any property in your buildProjects.xml file that says the build must fail on errors. There is a property that declares a build to fail on error.